# How can I set the widths of a two-row header table with table-layout: fixed?

Tags: html

the table header I want:

```
<table class="tabel_op_panou" style="margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px; width: 99%; table-layout:fixed;">
<tr>
    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 35%;">A</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="width: 25%;">B</th>
    <th colspan="3" style="width: 40%;">C</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="width: 8%;">B1</th>
    <th style="width: 17%;">B2</th>
    <th style="width: 8%;">C1</th>
    <th style="width: 17%;">C2</th>
    <th style="width: 15%;">C3</th>
</tr>
```

The problem is no matter how I set the widths, the 2nd row stays the same.  I tried percentages and fixed pixel widths.

Removing table-layout from the style seems to work but I need the fixed layout. Is there any way to do it while keeping "table-layout: fixed"?

I want the layout in the end to look something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rRJU7/) but with table-layout: fixed/

Comment: I want the second row of headers to have the specified widths. kinda like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rRJU7/) but with table-layout:fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[table-layout:fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/table-layout):

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and **col**
>   elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
>   subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

So, you can modify your code like this:

```
<table class="tabel_op_panou" style="margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px; width: 99%;border:1px solid grey;table-layout:fixed;">
    <col style="width: 35%;"/>
    <col style="width: 8%;"/>
    <col style="width: 17%;"/>
    <col style="width: 8%; "/>
    <col style="width: 17%;"/>
    <col style="width: 15%;"/>
<tr>
    <th rowspan="2" style="width: 35%; border:1px solid grey;">A</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="width: 25%; border:1px solid grey;">B</th>
    <th colspan="3" style="width: 40%; border:1px solid grey;">C</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="width: 8%; border:1px solid grey;">B1</th>
    <th style="width: 17%; border:1px solid grey;">B2</th>
    <th style="width: 8%; border:1px solid grey;">C1</th>
    <th style="width: 17%; border:1px solid grey;">C3</th>
    <th style="width: 15%; border:1px solid grey;">C4</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rRJU7/2/