# Set td width in table with table-layout: fixed

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

As far I know the column widths are determined by the first row of the table. My problem is the first td in table has colspan set to '2'. Here is how my table looks like. Important thing is I can not change the HTML structure of table.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>Personal Details</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Title: </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>Personal Details</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Title: </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>Personal Details</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Title: </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Title: </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

What I need is to set the width of td which contain `<ul>` element to 30%. So td colspan = '2' becomes some kind of header and the td elements below are split 30/70.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't read that part, seems the only way to do this would be to change the html and add cols in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841700/how-can-i-set-the-widths-of-a-two-row-header-table-with-table-layout-fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('strong').parents('tr').addClass('header_td'); // jquery line code...
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
table {   
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
table tr:not(.header_td){
    background : red;
    color:white;
}
table tr:not(.header_td) td:first-child{
    max-width:30%; 
    width:30%;
    background:green;
}
table tr:not(.header_td) td{
    max-width:69%;  // 69% just only beacause some extra padding by element it self doesn't make chage t your structure.
    width:69%;
    background:black;
}
.header_td{
    background : grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>Personal Details</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Title: </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>Personal Details</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Title: </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>Personal Details</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Title: </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Title: </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here i updated whole my answer with your **new requirement** please take a look here on it

Comment: This is great. I have complicated my issue even more. Could you please refer to this edit?

Comment: @user1346765 what you mean by complicated i can't getting you

Comment: Well, your answer is correct for my previous code where were only two 'tr' elements. Now I have added more elements so pseudo selector with 2 as argument :nth-child(2) won't work anymore.

Comment: @user1346765 have your html structure static or dynamic.?

Comment: @user1346765 can you give me idea about exact what you want ./??

Comment: @user1346765 Could you please refer to this edited answer?

Answer (score 1):

Take out `table-layout: fixed;` and add `td:first-child { width: 30% }` to your css.

http://jsfiddle.net/louis_feat/gcgk9y7e/

Comment: I think the point of the fixed layout is so that the word break will work

Comment: @Pete Fair point. Not much for it but to change the html (which I know s/he can't do). There's no browser-consistent workaround that I can see if the layout needs to be fixed...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using some pseudo selectors, it won't work in IE 6, 7 and 8 though:

```
table {
    table-layout: initial;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

tr:not(:first-child) td{
    width: 70%;
}

tr:not(:first-child) td:first-child {
    width: 30%;
}
```